# I want to add a middleware in .Net

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, authorization, middleware

the idea behind this middleware is to turn off or hide an api as a feature flag, so the middleware will interrupt the request and add an authorization claim to the user and to the user claim table that either enables the user or disables his capabilities to reach the api, I dont really know where to start with that or how to do it I am trying to research this some more i hope my explanation helps

Comment: Can`t you achieve it with roles?

Comment: To be perfectly honest, Im not sure, I used IdentityServer4 for authentication I also created a profile service to add new claims to the JWT payload I thought of doing something like this here but that wouldnt be right since the claim will be add ned to all users. I am using Identity User for my users my research lead me here https://www.tpeczek.com/2019/01/aspnet-core-middleware-and-authorization.html no sure about the implementation though

Comment: if you do not want to allow a user to access your API, you should not provide them authorization(using roles). Feature flags are basically to toggle a feature based upon configuration. you can use app.map and IConfiguration for path based features.